# Have configurable product display different information based on selected option?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, attributes, configurable-product

I know the image for each option can be set and will change based on which is currently selected, but can something like this be done for other information on the products page?

For example, displaying different heights or widths for different options, or displaying different related products for different options?